# Nuxt/Vue - how to run code before a page is rendered?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt app (SSR) that uses Django on the backend, for authenticating users i'm using the standard Django Session Auth.

I'm completely stuck on the part where i need to redirect user to the login page when the user is rendered. So what i need to do is to send a request to my Django backend that will return whether the user is authenticated or not. Is there any way i can execute code before the HTML in my page is rendered?

**What i tried:**

**Middleware**: I tried this with a middleware but for some reason Nuxt middlewares don't work with Axios. When i send the request from the Middleware, it won't send any Cookie along with the request so i will always be logged out (even when i'm logged in). This is a problem with Nuxt and not with the backend, because if i try the same request from a simple page it will work without any problem:

```
export default async function (context) {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkAuth',
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(function (response) {
    //Check if user is authenticated - response is always False
  }).catch(function (error) {
    //Handle error
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using SSR (Universal) or SPA?

Comment: I'm using SSR, i'm sorry for not including it, i'm editing now

Comment: I think, since middleware is executed server side you don't have access to the cookies that exist on the client.

Comment: Indeed, after looking on Github that seems to be the problem. If my app is SPA, will the middleware be exectued client side? And do you know a way to do this without the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using plugins. First you have to create a .js file in your /plugins folder. Then you have to include the plugins [] in your nuxt.config.js. Follow this guide to get more information. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Axios can be accessed using the context object in the middleware. Please read more about the context object(https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/context-helpers/). So your code would look like -

```
export default function (context) {
    return context.$axios.get("/endpoint").then(response=> { }).catch(error => {} )
}
```